# How to install LLama 2.0 on virtual Envirnoment

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-transfer, llama

I am trying to run llama on my local server. After running Quickstart.ipynb Iam getting error `llama_recipes not found`. I tried to install llama_recipes from directory but didn't work. Also while loading, I am getting error about `accelerator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a virtual environment
2. Clone repo:
   https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama-recipes
3. Install requirements from `dev_requirement.txt` an `requirements.txt` using command `pip install -r [filename].txt`
4. Move `llama_recipes` folder from `src` directory and `quickstart.ipynb` from examples directory to same directory.
5. Install/upgrade `jupyter` and `ipywidgets` if you are running jupyter notebook on VSCode.
6. if you still face dependecy error about accelerator/bitsandbytes
   edit `load_in_8bit=True` to `load_in_8bit=False`.